# Add custom fonts in C++ and call them by their family name in QML

Tags: c++, qt, fonts, qml

In my `qrc` file, I have the following fonts:

[image]

If I install them on the OS (Windows here), I will be able to call them in `QML` with the following name:

```
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

Label {
    id: label
    font.family: "Universalis ADF Std"
}
```

But if they're not installed, I'd still like to make them available to my `QML` files.

Of course, adding the fonts one by one with `QFontDatabase` works:

```
QDir    dir{"path/to/fonts"};
for (auto file : dir.entryList(QDir::Files))
{
    if (QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont("path/to/fonts/" + file))
        std::cerr << "Fail to add font " << file << std::endl;
}
```

But I won't be able to call the whole group with "Universalis ADF Std". Note that the `C++` part happens before loading the `QML` files. How could I do that?

Comment: " I won't be able to call the whole group with "Universalis ADF Std"" - how do you know that?

Comment: Because I tried it. The `Label` does not use the regular font.

Comment: Note that I could ultimately write a Powershell script to install the fonts on the computer. But I'd like to avoid to resort to this solution.

Comment: If you say the files are in the resource file why do you load then with `QDir`?

Comment: Did you try `FontLoader`?

Comment: I just wanted to write a quick draft code to get the filenames. I did try `FontLoader` without result: `FontLoader { id: font; name: "Universalis ADF Std" }`

Comment: Each call to `addApplicationFont` returns an int. What do you get if you pass that int to `QFontDatabase::applicationFontFamilies`? What do you get if you list all the fonts (again via `QFontDatabase`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [peppe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1873944/peppe)'s post, I realized that the code I've produced works. I had forgotten that I need to reboot the computer after installing and uninstalling the fonts on Windows. It was messing with my program as I couldn't really know if the fonts were correctly loaded. To summarize:

1. Check that the font you want to load isn't already available on the OS. If this is the case, uninstall it and **reboot** your computer
2. Load your font from C++ before running the QML files
3. In order to use all the styles of your font (bold, italic, etc.), call your font by using its family name: `font.family: "Universalis ADF Std"`